# Как сделать, чтобы текстуры были непрозрачны?

Tags: opengl

Как сделать, чтобы  текстуры были непрозрачны?
Здесь у меня получается одна текстура прозрачна другая непрозрачна и та которая непрозрачна перекрывает прозрачную, что не так?

```
#include<cstdlib>

#include<gl\glut.h>
#include<math.h>
#include <GL/glaux.h>

float WinWid=400.0;
float WinHei=400.0;
float Angle=0.0, Scale=1.0;

const float PI =3.141592653; 
const float height = 3; 
double x, y, z; 
float angleX, angleY;

unsigned int textures[2];
void LoadTextures()
{
AUX_RGBImageRec *texture1=auxDIBImageLoadA("Debug/qr.bmp "),

*texture2=auxDIBImageLoadA("Debug/q2.bmp ");

glGenTextures(2,&textures[0]);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,textures[0]);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,3,texture1->sizeX,  texture1->sizeY,0,GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,texture1->data );

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,textures[1]);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,3,texture2->sizeX,  texture2->sizeY,0,GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,texture2->data );

}
void Draw()
{
       // glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glPushMatrix();

        gluLookAt(x,y+height,z,x-sin(angleX/180*PI),y+height+(tan(angleY/180*PI)),z-cos(angleX/180*PI), 0, 1, 0);

 glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,textures[0]);       
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2f(0.0,0.0);glVertex3f(10.0,-10.0,-10.0);

glTexCoord2f(0.0,1.0);glVertex3f(-10.0,-10.0,-10.0);

glTexCoord2f(1.0,1.0);glVertex3f(-10.0,10,-10.0);

glTexCoord2f(1.0,0.0);glVertex3f(10.0,10,-10.0);
glEnd();
 glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,textures[1]);       
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2f(0.0,0.0);glVertex3f(-10.0,-10.0,10.0);

glTexCoord2f(0.0,1.0);glVertex3f(-10.0,10.0,10.0);

glTexCoord2f(1.0,1.0);glVertex3f(10.0,10.0,10.0);

glTexCoord2f(1.0,0.0);glVertex3f(10.0,-10.0,10.0);
glEnd();
glPopMatrix();

  glutSwapBuffers();
}

void Timer(int =0)
{

        Draw();
        glutPostRedisplay();
        glutTimerFunc(50, Timer, 0);
}

void Initialize()
{

    //glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        gluPerspective(90, 1, 0, 1);

        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

        LoadTextures(); 
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glEnable(GL_BLEND);
       glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

}
void Keyboard(unsigned char key, int az, int ax)
{
        switch(key)
        {

case 'w':

    x -= (float)sin(angleX/180*PI);
z -= (float)cos(angleX/180*PI);
 break;

case 's':
    x += (float)sin(angleX/180*PI);
z += (float)cos(angleX/180*PI) ;

                break;

case 'a':

    x += (float)sin(( angleX + 90)/180*PI) ;
z += (float)cos(( angleX + 90)/180*PI) ;

                break;

case 'd':

    x += (float)sin(( angleX - 90)/180*PI);
z += (float)cos(( angleX - 90)/180*PI) ;
                break;

        }
}

void Mouse(int ax, int  ay)
{

    angleX = ax-640; 
       angleY = (240 - ay)/2;

}
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
        glutInit(&argc, argv);

        glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH|GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_RGB);

        glutInitWindowSize(WinWid, WinHei);
        glutInitWindowPosition(100, 200);
        glutCreateWindow("Lesson 03");
        glutDisplayFunc(Draw);
        glutTimerFunc(50, Timer, 0);
        Initialize();
         glutKeyboardFunc(Keyboard);
         glutPassiveMotionFunc(Mouse);
        glutMainLoop();
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Код отредактировал.
Моргание осталось , и при управлении с клавиатуры.

Answer (score 1):

Прозрачность нужно включить

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Подозреваю, что буфер глубины (DepthBuffer) тоже нужно включать.

Comment: Включил , ничего не изменилось.(код отредактировал)

Comment: Включить буфера глубины нужно

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)

И чистить z-буфер вместе с буфером цвета

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

Comment: А буфер глубины куда добавить ?

Comment: Включение — в инициализацию, чистку — перед каждым рендером (т.е. заменить свою строчку с glClear на приведённую).

Comment: Теперь не могу найти текстуры. (код отредактировал)

Comment: Не в том месте изменил glClear.

Comment: Теперь при движении мышки текстуры то исчезают то опять появляются,
как бы моргание такое получается. (код отредактировал)



Код отредактировал. Моргание осталось , и при управлении с клавиатуры.

Comment: И да, в глуте тоже нужно инициализировать буфер глубины, GLUT_DEPTH ставить.

При управлении клавой морганий нет?